# Why does rendered content of a TWebBrowser saved as JPEG loses quality?

Tags: delphi, twebbrowser

I use the procedure below to create a JPG file from a TWebbrowser
That is resulting in a JPG looking OK 
Then I load this JPG to a TcxImage control from DevExpress in order to print it. And that messes up my image so it isn't possible to see the map (it is a portion of a map from Google Maps)
The code for loading the image is

```
imgPrint.Picture.LoadFromFile(lImage);
```

I don't quite get why this is looking so bad already on screen.
I do it this way in order to be able to print the map. 
It could also be done direct from the TWebBrowser but ther I have no control of the output size and adding my own headers and footers are tricky.

```
procedure TfrmJsZipExplorer.actSaveExecute(Sender: TObject);
var
  ViewObject : IViewObject;
  r : TRect;
  Bitmap: TBitmap;
begin
  if WebBrowser1.Document <> nil then
    begin
      WebBrowser1.Document.QueryInterface(IViewObject, ViewObject) ;
      if Assigned(ViewObject) then
        try
          Bitmap := TBitmap.Create;
          try
            r := Rect(0, 0, WebBrowser1.Width, WebBrowser1.Height) ;
            Bitmap.Height := WebBrowser1.Height;
            Bitmap.Width := WebBrowser1.Width;
            ViewObject.Draw(DVASPECT_CONTENT, 1, nil, nil, Application.Handle, bitmap.Canvas.Handle, @r, nil, nil, 0);
            with TJPEGImage.Create do
              try
                Assign(Bitmap);
                SaveToFile(lImagefile);
              finally
                Free;
            end;
          finally
            Bitmap.Free;
          end;
        finally
          ViewObject._Release;
        end;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: Can't you just skip the whole JPEG part and assign the rendered bitmap directly to your `TcxImage`, something like `imgPrint.Picture.Assign(Bitmap);` ?

Comment: I could do that but the images are saved for a period of time and JPG are not as 'spacy' as BMP

Comment: Then give a try to `CompressionQuality` property. If even the highest available quality setting won't fit your visual needs, then you might try to consider to use a different image format, e.g. PNG.

Comment: I have set CompressionQuality := 100; but the image it being messed up when loading it to the imagecontrol. Even using the standard Delphi TImage messes it up.
If I open the file using AcdSee then it looks OK so I may have to look at the loading instead of the saving

Answer (score 4):

***How to improve a saved JPEG image quality ?***

You may set the [`CompressionQuality`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.Imaging.jpeg.TJPEGImage.CompressionQuality) property of your saved image to the lowest compression, but highest image quality value. That will improve visual quality of the output image. Setting this property to 100 will result in better image quality, but larger file size:

```
with TJPEGImage.Create do
try
  Assign(Bitmap);      
  CompressionQuality := 100;
  SaveToFile(lImagefile);
finally
  Free;
end;
```

***It is necessary to use JPEG format for this image archive ?***

If you're not limited only to JPEG format for you image archive, consider to use a different format, such as PNG. If you'd decide to use a PNG format with [`TPNGImage`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.Imaging.pngimage.TPngImage) class, there's the [`CompressionLevel`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.Imaging.pngimage.TPngImage.CompressionLevel) property, which allows you to specify the compression level of a saved image and which directly affects the size of the output file, but unlike the JPEG format compression with keeping the same visual quality. Setting this property to 9 will result in full compression to be used, which produces just smaller file size, the quality remains same as if no compression (0 value) would be used:

```
uses
  PNGImage;

with TPNGImage.Create do
try
  Assign(Bitmap);
  CompressionLevel := 9;
  SaveToFile(lImagefile);
finally
  Free;
end;
```

Comment: Even if saved as BMP the quality is still to poor when loading to the TcxImage component.
I have to save it to a file for 2 reasons - the images are stored for a period of time and the printout is done from some other form than the one used to generate it (this could be changed in time)

Comment: That's strange. I don't know `TcxImage`, but I don't get, why would assigning a bitmap to it degrade the bitmap's quality. Don't you have something like `Stretched` property set to True ?

Comment: as far as TcxImage the main difference (as I see it) is that it can be printed using the PrintingSystem of DevExpress.
And Stretched is set to false and I can't see any other that might have anything to do with this.
I have also checked that it is set to the correct graphicstype when trying another format.

Comment: One another thing comes to mi mind. The bounds rectangle you're passing to the `IViewObject::Draw` is probably too large, since you're using the web browser's bounds rectangle and it seems, that web browser uses some sort of inner border around the displayed web site. The size of that passed rectangle is critical, since by this size is the content scaled to the target canvas. In other words, the `IViewObject::Draw` will stretch draw the web browser content by the passed `r` parameter to the output `Bitmap` and that may distort its visual appearence.

Comment: but viewing the image in AcdSee or importing it to CorelDRAW! gives very nice looking pictures
The window showing the webbrowser is opened in size 800 * 600

Comment: Are we talking about the bitmap on which you're rendering the web browser's content, right ? Because if so, then it sounds strange. If you save it to a file and it looks as expected in your image browser, I can't see the reason, why wouldn't look the same as if you'd load it to a `TImage`, `TcxImage` or just render it in your application.

Comment: The TWebbrowser is opened in a window sized 800 * 600 and the saved as image using the above code.
If you send me a mail at  oz8hp @ hotmail . com I could return a copy of the image for you to see